# how to extract path from file location using shell

Tags: shell, shell-script, filenames

how to extract path location from below given string.

```
/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/bin/tnslsnr
```

expected output.

```
/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/bin
```

(or)

```
/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/bin/
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Use the shell's suffix removal feature

```
str=/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/bin/tnslsnr
path=${str%/*}
echo "$path"
```

In general, `${parameter%word}` removes `word` from the end of `parameter`.  In our case, we want to remove the final slash and all characters which follow: `/*`.

The above produces:

```
/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/bin
```

#### Use dirname

[dirname](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dirname.html) can be used to strip the last component from a path:

```
$ dirname -- "$str"
/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

```
start cmd:> dirname "/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/bin/tnslsnr"
/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/bin

file_path="/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/bin/tnslsnr"
dir_path_woslash="${file_path%/*}"
echo "$dir_path_woslash"
/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/bin

shopt -s extglob
dir_path_wslash="${file_path%%+([^/])}"
echo "$dir_path_wslash"
/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/bin/
```